# Python - Intersection on multiple sets on the condition that empty sets are to be excluded

Tags: python, set, intersection, set-intersection

What's the simplest way in Python of performing an intersection on multiple sets on the condition that empty sets, if any, are to be excluded? I tried using a list comprehension but in the example below, it only works if a is not empty.

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {1, 4, 8, 9}
c = {1, 5, 10, 15}
d = {1, 100, 200}
e = set()
MySets = [b, c, d, e]
result = a.intersection(*[s for s in MySets if s])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `set.intersection` explicitly will work as long as there is at least one non-empty set:

```
result = set.intersection(*(s for s in [a, b, c, d, e] if s))
```

If there is a possibility of *all* sets being empty, check the result of filtering before calling `set.intersection`. The assignment expression makes this a bit easier.

```
result = set.intersection(*non_empty) if (non_empty := list(x for x in [a, b, c, d, e] if s) else set()
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But I'm curious to know why there must be an empty set (which isn't an issue at all). Not sure I understand. Can you please elaborate?